# Targeting device aspect ratio below a certain threshold in CSS

Tags: css, media-queries

My brain is borked.

How can I target all devices with a device aspect ratio below 16/9. i.e fatter than 16/9? This doesn't seem to work.

This for portrait only within an iOS/Android cordova app.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried aspect ratio in general? If the device is wider than 16/9 in landscape, and you're in portrait, try:

```
@media ALL and (max-aspect-ratio: 9/16) { 
    /* style your super tall content here */
}
```

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zo7xuj15/1/

The browser should occupy your device's screen either way, and here you won't have to worry about orientation. Note in the fiddle that the style within the media query activates only when you go super tall (skinnier than 9/16).

Comment: aspect-ratio and device-aspect-ratio are two different media features. This is more likely an issue of which one to use, rather than simply doing the inverse - though based on what is given in the question I can't say for sure.

Comment: They are different media queries for sure, but a browser's a browser and if he's asking about styling for a device aspect ratio in landscape, aspect-ratio in general should work for this application.

Answer (score 0):

Targeting *all* devices / resolutions; is very difficult in my opinion as they have different default mobile viewport settings and default mobile browser settings. Often times you have to treat each supported devices differently, and sometimes much differently when handling media, videos, animations, etc..

You should stick to supporting per device *and* resolution.

*EG.*

**iPhone** (Mobile Safari) Resolution X, Y, Z

**iPad** (Mobile Safari) Resolution X, Y, Z

**Android** (Chrome Webkit) Resolution X, Y, X

**Blackberry** (Opera) Resolution X, Y, X

You get the point...